# Highcharts bug - label formatter function does not fire with multiple axis

Tags: highcharts, yaxis

I have a chart with multiple yAxis and I want to format each one differently. However, it seems with multiple yAxis, the label formatter function does not fire at all. Here's my options:

```
{
  chart: {
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    pinchType: 'none',
    height: 320,
    events: {
      load: (e) => {
      }
    }
  },
  plotOptions: {
    line: {
      states: {
        hover: {
          enabled: true
        }
      },
      animation: {
        duration: 750
      }
    },
    series: {
      lineWidth: 2,
    }
  },
  series : [
    { name: 'charts',
      type: 'line',
      id: 0,
      dataGrouping: {
        groupPixelWidth: 8
      },
    },
    { name: 'marketcap',
      type: 'line',
      id: 1,
      color: '#1fd3a3',
      dataGrouping: {
        groupPixelWidth: 8
      },
    },
    { name: 'volume',
      type: 'area',
      id: 2,
      color: '#ddd',
      lineWidth: 1,
      dataGrouping: {
        groupPixelWidth: 8
      },
    }
  ],
  navigator: {
    enabled: false
  },
  scrollbar: {
      enabled: false
  },
  rangeSelector: {
    enabled: false
  },
  // responsive: {
  //   rules: [{
  //       condition: {
  //           maxWidth: 500
  //       },
  //   }]
  // },
  xAxis: {
    // crosshair: {
    //     width: 1,
    //     color: 'rgba(255,255,255,.5)'
    // },
    visible: true,
    type: 'datetime'
  },
  yAxis: [
    {
      opposite: false,
      gridLineWidth: 0,
      minorGridLineWidth: 0,
      height: '75%',
      tickAmount: 5,
      labels: {
        formatter: () => {
          // this does not fire
          console.log('firing!!');
          return this.value
        }
      }
    },
    {
      opposite: true,
      gridLineWidth: 0,
      minorGridLineWidth: 0,
      height: '75%',
      tickAmount: 5
    },
    {
      top: '75%',
      height: '25%',
      opposite: false,
      gridLineWidth: 0,
      minorGridLineWidth: 0,
      visible: false,
    },
  ],
  tooltip: {
    followPointer: true,
    shared: true,
  },
  credits: { enabled: false }
```

}

Notice that I have 3 yAxis, and within each of those I have different keys and values. I need to have a custom format for each, but when I try to use the formatter function, nothing happens. Using the format string value works, but it does not allow me to format the string the way I want. Any ideas?

Comment: you have use formatter for all yAxis not just only first check http://jsfiddle.net/p2b5xqhy/

Comment: For the one axis you do have a formatter, it is working: https://jsfiddle.net/ewolden/a6zouqLu/15/

Comment: Additionally, arrow functions change the context of the callback so you won't be able to return 'this.value'.